# How Rails serves concurrent requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I will divide this question in *two parts*.
**Part 1:**
How Rails serves concurrent requests to the same action?
Is Rails serves concurrent requests in **different Threads** or Rails serve in a **queue**?

**Part 2:**
Why I ask?
I make a very specific project. And now I thinking about change the application architecture if necessary.

### Question

**Foreword**
I have controller with action calculate. 
It seems like that:

```
 def calculate
      first_player_code  = Code.find(params[:first_player_id])
      second_player_code = Code.find(params[:second_player_id])
      File.open("first_player_code.rb", "w"){|file| file << first_player_code}
      File.open("second_player_code.rb", "w"){|file| file << second_player_code}
      system("ruby calculate.rb")
 end
```

**calculate.rb** is contains script, which uses files  "**first_player_code.rb**" and "**second_player_code.rb**".
This script make **JSON** file as result and send it to browser.

**More information**
"**first_player_code.rb**" and "**second_player_code.rb**" contains Ruby classes.
In **"calculate.rb"** i **requiring these files** and **making objects** from classes, which are in these files.
I just didn't find another way to do this (without using Files).

**The question itself**
Are there **synchronization** problems?

Comment: Rails doesn't handle concurrent requests. Just one at a time. This is job of the web server to spin up more threads or workers (or use evented I/O) to achieve some concurrency

Comment: The question is: what runs your rails app?

Comment: If I correctly understood, I can't rely on Rails(standart) parallelism(if I do not realize it myself). 
I will add more information about script in main post.

Comment: what "standard parallelism" are you talking about? There's none. Rails, as a framework, processes requests sequentially, one after another. There might be, of course, several instances of rails running concurrently, but this is outside of business of Rails itself.

Comment: Seems like I have wrong understanding of Rails. 
Can you suggest some resources where I can learn about how Rails works?

Comment: This one is good: https://rebuilding-rails.com/

Comment: Thanks. Also I have one more question.
Is there a possibility to get an object if we have string with class inside.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean

Answer (score 1):

You would typically configure a web server like [Puma](https://github.com/puma/puma) that uses threads to handle requests concurrently and pass them to the Rails application. True threading is not possible with regular MRI ruby because the Global Interpreter Lock prevents more than one thread from running at a time.

For long running processes you should try to prevent blocking by passing those off to background jobs. [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) is a good option for this.

Also see https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby

Comment: Thanks, but i think, that the best way here - is to reorganize the architecture of my app. And try to not use files.